# Can naturally-occurring defined infinite sets (evens,odds, naturals, rationals, .., complex,) andor their respective elements be expressed explicitly?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, notation

By "explicitly" I mean without needing necessarily to rely on the understood meaning conveyed by the shorthand of its blackboard-bold Latin uppercase letter representation. If not, then what is the minimum required number of naturally occurring not-explicitly-defined sets upon which any other set within complex numbers can be expressed?   A related question: How does one define an all-inclusive possibly infinite set of some type of object? For those common naturally-occurring sets there is shorthand, e.g. "all +,0,- integers '±n' = {..,-2,-1,0,1,2,..} := ℤ" ⇒ n,-n ∈ ℤ. But how about, for instance, some subset such as a parity (e.g. "all evens", or more complicated patterns e.g. skipping one more than the previous with some basis such as {..-11,-7,-4,-2,-1,1,4,8,13,..} or for this matter primes (with a self-contained definition or similar), or some subset of algebraics (e.g. all complex that can be expressed with rational powers)? Is there a purely symbolic (consistent) means to convey these different clutches of numbers, without using a 'shortcut'?

Comment: Odd numbers may be represented as all numbers that can be expressed as $(2n + 1) ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z},~$ while rational numbers may be represented as all numbers that can be expressed as $\displaystyle \frac{p}{q} ~: ~p,q \in \Bbb{Z}, q \neq 0$.

Comment: Thankye, @user2661923.  How about proper supersets integers, naturals, reals, or complex numbers?

Comment: This question is difficult to parse. What do you mean by "naturally-occurring"? The natural numbers are formulated by the Peano Axioms. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms The real numbers are also constructed - there are a few ways to do this like Dedekind Completeness. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_of_the_real_numbers The complex numbers can then be defined as $\{ x + iy:\ x\in\mathbb{R},\ y\in\mathbb{R}\ \}.$

Comment: The sequence $\{1,4,8,13, \cdots\}$ may be represented by $\langle a_n\rangle$, where $a_1 = 1$ and for $n \geq 2, ~a_n = a_{(n-1)} + (n+1).$

Comment: @Adam Rubinson  Combining axioms with "set of all Naturals", can other sets be based upon them? with, or without, additional axioms?

Comment: @user2661923 True enough a sequence. Why angled brackets for a_n instead of curly braces? And what of a continuous domain (but perhaps analogous to a sequence)?

Comment: @Adam Rubinson  makes sense.  How about ℕ, ℤ, or ℝ?

Comment: Like I said, N is defined using Peano axioms. Z is simply positive integers united with negative integers. R is harder to define but if you're interested then see the link in my comment above.

Comment: I was taught the arbitrary nomenclature of $\langle a_n\rangle$ to represent a sequence.  I do not think that this nomenclature is universally accepted.  My knowledge of Number Theory or Topology is inadequate to discuss such concepts as a continuous domain.

Comment: You might also be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)

Comment: Thanks.  To whomever downvoted the post: a reason would be helpful.

Comment: +1: to your question, taking it from -2 to -1.  Well, this is embarrassing; there is no quality control on (anonymous) down-voting.  Personally, I regard your question as primarily an interpretation question, rather than a specific problem to be solved.  Therefore, I think that the normal protocol, as documented in [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) does not apply here.

Comment: Ty for the kind words, @user2661923. Feel free to revise/improve its content or change the tags.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start by giving you the standard set-theory answer, which I will call the "material set theory" answer.

There is an axiom known as the "axiom of infinity" which, in one form, states $\exists \omega (\emptyset \in \omega \land \forall x \in \omega (x \cup \{x\} \in \omega))$.

Keep in mind that in set theory, everything is a set. So it makes sense to say $x \cup \{x\}$ - this is the set such that $y \in (x \cup \{x\})$ if and only if either $y \in x$ or $y = x$.

This permits us to explicitly define the natural numbers as the unique set $\mathbb{N}$ which satisfies the following property:

$\emptyset \in \mathbb{N} \land \forall x \in \mathbb{N} (x \cup \{x\} \in \mathbb{N}) \land \forall N ((\emptyset \in N \land \forall x \in N (x \cup \{x\} \in N)) \implies \mathbb{N} \subseteq N)$

Let's translate this into non-set theory language.

Define $0 = \emptyset$, and given some set $n$, define $addOne(n)$ to be the set $n \cup \{n\}$.

Then $\mathbb{N}$ is defined to be the unique set such that (a) $0 \in \mathbb{N}$, (b) for all $n \in \mathbb{N}, addOne(b) \in \mathbb{N}$, and (c) $\mathbb{N}$ satisfies induction (that is, satisfies $\forall N ((0 \in N \land \forall x \in N (addOne(x) \in N)) \implies \mathbb{N} \subseteq N)$).

We can explicitly define ordered pairs and Cartesian products in set theory. This enables us to explicitly construct $\mathbb{Z} = \{(a, b) \in \mathbb{N}^2 | a = 0 \lor b = 0\}$. The idea is that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $(n, 0)$ is "positive $n$" and $(0, n)$ is "negative $n$".

From here, we can explicitly construct the rational numbers as $\mathbb{Q} = \{(a, b) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{N} | b \neq 0 \land $ the gcd of $a$ and $b$ is $1\}$. Obviously, we'd have to define "gcd" first, but this isn't too difficult. We represent a reduced fraction $\frac{a}{b}$ as $(a, b)$.

For evens and odds, we'd first have to explicitly define addition and multiplication. Then, defining $1 = addOne(0)$ and $2 = addOne(1)$, we could define the even (natural) numbers as $\{n \in \mathbb{N} | \exists m \in \mathbb{Z} (n = 2 \cdot m)\}$ and the odd (natural) numbers as $\{n \in \mathbb{N} | \exists m \in \mathbb{Z} (n = (2 \cdot m) + 1)\}$. We can, of course, extend these definitions to $\mathbb{Z}$.

For real numbers, the situation is more complicated. One can either define the real numbers in terms of Cauchy sequences or Dedekind cuts. For more information, see a real analysis textbook.

For complex numbers, we simply define $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}^2$. We write $a + bi$, where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, as shorthand for $(a, b)$. Once we have addition and multiplication defined in $\mathbb{R}$, it's easy to extend this to $\mathbb{C}$ by defining $(a + bi) \cdot (c + di) = (a \cdot c - b \cdot d) + (a \cdot d + b \cdot c) i$. In particular, we see that $(0 + 1i) \cdot (0 + 1i) = -1 + 0i$.

Now, I will pivot towards a very different answer based in category theory. This is what I would term the "structural view" of numbers.

A set $\mathbb{N}$, together with some element $z \in \mathbb{N}$ and some function $addOne : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, is said to "be the structure of natural numbers" if for every set $M$, element $m \in M$, and function $f : M \to M$, there is exactly one function $g : \mathbb{N} \to M$ such that $g(z) = m$ and, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $g(addOne(n)) = f(g(n))$.

Notice that on this view, there is no one single "set of natural numbers". Instead, the natural numbers are defined by a property. Any two natural number structures $(\mathbb{N}, z, addOne)$, $(\mathbb{N}', z', addOne')$ can be put into bijection $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N'}$ such that $f(z) = z'$ and for all $n$, $f(addOne(n)) = addOne'(f(n))$ in exactly one way.

It doesn't matter which specific structure of natural numbers we pick. It just matters that we have one of them.

For example, given one natural numbers structure $(\mathbb{N}, z, addOne)$, we can define another by setting $N = \{(n, n) | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, $z' = (z, z)$, and $addOne'(n, n) = (addOne(n), addOne(n))$. $N$ and $\mathbb{N}$ will be practically indistinguishable in terms of their structure, so there's no particular reason to use one over the other.

Similarly, a set $\mathbb{Z}$ together with an element $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ and operations $addOne, subtractOne : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $n = addOne(subtractOne(n)) = subtractOne(addOne(n))$ is said to be a "structure of integers" if for all sets $M$, together with an element $m \in M$ and functions $f,g : M \to M$ such that for all $k \in M$, $k = f(g(k)) = g(f(k))$, there is a unique function $h : \mathbb{Z} \to M$ such that $h(z) = m$ and for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $h(addOne(n)) = f(h(n))$ and $h(subtractOne(n)) = g(h(n))$.

Just like with the natural numbers, there is no one "set of integers". Just like the natural numbers, one can put any two structures of integers into a nice bijection with each other in exactly 1 way. It doesn't matter which "structure of the integers" one uses - it only matters that there is one.

Defining the structural properties of $\mathbb{Q}$ is harder. One can define a "rational numbers structure" as a set $\mathbb{Q}$ together with a surjective function $divide : \mathbb{Z} \times \{n \in \mathbb{Z} | n \neq 0\} \to \mathbb{Q}$ such that $divide(a, b) = divide(c, d)$ if and only if $ad = bc$.

Again, rational number structures are not unique - only unique up to bijection. And again, it doesn't matter which rational numbers structure you pick as long as there is one.

The same trend holds for real numbers and complex numbers, though I won't get into it here.

From a structural perspective, the "material set theory" constructions are really just ways of coming up with a specific structure of natural numbers/integers/rational numbers/real numbers/complex numbers. There is no single "set of natural numbers" - there is only a property which (almost uniquely) defines it.

Comment: Ty for the detailed response. Question: What do you mean by letting zero equal nullset?

Comment: @11qq00 I mean that we are defining $0$ to be the empty set. Just pretend that $0$ is an ordinary variable name.